# Oppose against, react against or disagree against

Tags: prepositions

He ...... strongly against my suggestion. He refused to discuss it.

1. opposed
2. reacted
3. disagreed

Can someone please tell me the right answer? I don't think it's disagreed, because you don't see the verb "disagree" before "against", so I think it's either opposed or reacted.

Cheers.

Comment: Neither do you see 'opposed against', because 'to oppose' means 'to be against'.

Answer (score 1):

**Oppose** itself means talking, reacting or in general, being against something. Hence it makes no sense at all to use the word ***against*** here again. Also the adverb **strongly** should be placed before verb *oppose* to make sense.

> He *strongly* **opposed**  my suggestion. He refused to discuss it.

**React** would be correct here, however the adverb placement would matter.

> He *strongly* **reacted** against my suggestion. He refused to discuss it.

**Disagree** is just not correct and doesn't make much sense in this context. If you wish to use it, then:

> He strongly **disagreed** *with* my suggestion. He refused to discuss it.

Comment: _Reacted strongly_ seems a perfectly OK order to me.

Comment: @mdewey Yes true. I usually have the habit of writing adverb prior to verb, that's why. I will edit. Thank you.